# how to cv2.imencode and imdecode (jpeg) for diffret QF values?

Tags: jpeg, encode, opencv, image-compression, python

I need to use open cv functions: `cv2.imencode,cv2.imdecode` to compress (jpeg) and decompress (jpeg) for different QF values.
The picture is '`bridge.ppm`' from https://imagecompression.info/test_images/

I've tried:

```
bridge = cv2.imread('./bridge.ppm')
bridge_en = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', bridge)
bridge_de = cv2.imdecode('.jpeg', bridge_en)
cv2.imshow('image',bridge_de)
```

but I'm getting an error in the 2nd line saying: `"Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'buf'".`

Also, how can I change and test different QF values?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look to the documentation for [imencode](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) and [imdecode](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e)

`imencode` returns two values, the encoded buffer is the second one. And `imdecode` accepts the encoded buffer and a flag. So:

```
bridge = cv2.imread('./bridge.ppm')
bridge_en = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', bridge)[1] # you need the second value
bridge_de = cv2.imdecode(bridge_en, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # or any other flag, same as 'imread'
cv2.imshow('image',bridge_de)
```

Comment: Thanks!
Do u know how can I test it on different QFs?

Comment: open the documentation? it tells you the available flags/settings for imencode.